# Get UsedRange for one column only in Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop

Using Microsoft's Excel Interop I am reading a spreadsheet. I have no problems getting the used range for the entire sheet, but I want to get the number of rows used for one column only. Here is an example of my sheet:

[image]

As you can see, the used range for Column A is only 3 rows, whilst for Column B it is 5 rows. When I used my current code:

```
int rows = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
```

..it always returns "5". How do I specify that I only want the used range for one cell?

Answer (score 0):

The UsedRange in Excel applies to the worksheet not individual columns.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732(v=office.15).aspx). 
You can get the last row for a particular column using something like this:

```
With yourExcelSheet
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lrCol).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
End With
```

Where 'yourExcelSheet' is the worksheet and needs to be declared/assigned, 'lrow' is the last row you require and 'lrcol' is the column number (A=1, B=2 etc.)

Apols but this snippet is derived from vb.net/vba and not c# so you will need to deal with any required conversion; but thought it may help.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Used Cells in Column A you can try this way

```
// Get the last cell used in the Column A
 var lastCell = sheet.Range["A:A"].SpecialCells(
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell
)
    // get the lastColumn used
    int lastcolumn = lastCell.column;

    // get the lastRow used
    int lastRow = lastCell.Row;
```

Comment: This is also giving the UsedRange's last row value. @Ram